# rippled css border in safari 6.0.2 when using border-radius

Tags: safari, webkit, css

As per title, I've encountered quite a weird issue on Safari, not sure if it's a well known one but I really didn't know how to research other threads about it.

I created a few css buttons, they look pretty neat in chrome, firefox, and on another version of safari I've tested on a retina macbook pro (6.0)

This is how the buttons look on most recent browsers:
http://d.pr/i/cHzX

My macbook air, however, runs safari 6.0.3, and that's how Safari 6.0.3.shows the borders:
http://d.pr/i/fcfl

Does anyone have any idea about how this kind of bug can be fixed?

This is the css (sass) that generates these buttons:

```
    .button{
      position:relative;
      z-index:1;
      display:block;
      width:175px;
      margin:0 15.5px;
      cursor:pointer;

      span{

        @include border-radius(9999em);
        display:block;
        width:175px;
        height:48px;
        line-height:48px;
        font-size:1.4em;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;

        &:before{
          @include border-radius(9999em);

          margin-top:5px;
          content:'.';
          text-indent:-9999em;
          position:absolute;
          z-index:-1;
          top:0;
          left:0;
          width:177px;
        }
      }

      &:active{
        outline:none;
        top:4px;

        span{
          &:before{
            top:-4px;
          }
        }

      }

      &:focus{
        outline:none;
      }
    }

    .orange-button span{
      @include background(linear-gradient(#FDAC26, #FB6336));
      border:1px solid #6B2B10;
      text-shadow:0 1px 0 #6B2B10;

      &:before{
        background:#AF431D;
        color:#AF431D;
        border-bottom:1px solid #6B2B10;
      }
    }

    .green-button span{
      @include background(linear-gradient(#7EC84B, #73B543));
      border:1px solid #3B5A22;
      text-shadow:0 1px 0 #3B5A22;

      &:before{
        background:#649039;
        color:#649039;
        border-bottom:1px solid #3B5A22;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below to every css class where you have border-radius:9999em

```
-webkit-border-radius:9999em;
-moz-border-radius:9999em;
```

safari and chrome use -webkit and -moz is used my mozilla.

Comment: This line of code:
        
        @include border-radius(9999em);

already takes care of all the vendor specific css. My problem lies elsewhere.